# Unable to publish latest build because of sensitive permission issue

Tags: android, flutter, permissions, apk, release

Google not allowed to roll out new build. Giving error sensitive permission issue.

In my flutter app, 'android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES' sensitive permission was added by 'open_file' plugin. Earlier i can upload build, but as per google current policy need to declare sensitive permission.

So I removed sensitive permissions which are not required in my app and tried to publish again. Still google didn`t allow to publish the latest build because this permission has been found in my previous testing build. I tried to change the testing build but didn't succeed. When i tried to change testing build that time google show sensitive permission issue in my previous production & previous testing build.
Please suggest me, how can i publish the new build.

Answer (score 0):

Use [open_filex](https://pub.dev/packages/open_filex) package, Remove '`android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES`' permission from android manifest and upload latest build in app console.

Open filex package has Removed `REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES` permission in Android to comply with GooglePlay publish policies.

Comment: I have already removed that permission from new build.

Comment: did you removed open_file package from pubspec.yaml?

Comment: No, i add ```<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" tools:node="remove"/>``` in my AndroidManifest.xml file. so this can remove REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission from my build

Comment: you need to remove open_file package from pubspec.yaml then issue is resolve.